# How to find the storage metrics based on file type in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, reports, storage, metrics

We would like to know if it's possible to get the storage metrics based on document type for a SharePoint Online site collection meaning how much space is occupied by each type of document.

Let me know if there are any options via pnp-powershell or any api.

Answer (score 0):

I cant think of an easy way to achieve this. All ways are slightly complex since you would need to use csom to iterate over all DocLibs in the site collection and tally them up manually.

There might be an option to pull some information about a single file type from search, but that would not cover all types...